# Is there a straightforward way to concatenate two or more matrices and at the same time avoid repeating elements?

Tags: matlab

Say we want to concatenate two matrices
a=[2 3 6] , b=[0 9 3 2 8 2]
but we don't want any repetitive elements in the concatenated matrix. 
in other words we want c to be
c=[2 3 6 0 9 8]
Is there a built-in function that does that for us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

% You could use the union function to accomplish this

```
a = [2 3 6];        % array a
b = [0 9 3 2 8 2];  % array b
```

% Use the union function to concatenate a and b. It lists an item that appears in  either array once.

```
c = union(a,b, 'stable');  %  adding 'stable' keeps your current order
```